# How to format all my vscode files from 4 space indentation to 2 spaces?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, visual-studio-code

How to format all vscode files in my application folder so that all existing codes be formatted to two spaces from 4 space indentation?

I understand that at the bottom of my VSStudio web editor, I can click on `Spaces` to change the code indention/spacing of a particular file.  I have several files though - I have copied and paste some code from `React-Bootstrap` docs (e.g navbar, list group, jumbotron).

I am also trying to use bootstrap in my `REACT` folders that has built in boiler plate codes that does not match with bootstraps boiler plate codes.  I just want to be able to synchronize all codes into one type of indention to make the codes cleaner and readable.

Is there an easy way, or a keyboard short cut perhaps, or a vscode built in programming that allows all codes to be follow the same number of spacing/indentation to all files in my project folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40):

**How to turn 4 spaces indents in all files in VS Code to 2 spaces**

- Open file search
- Turn on Regular Expressions
- Enter: `((( {2})(?: {2}))(\b|(?!=[,'";\.:\*\\\/\{\}\[\]\(\)])))` in the search field
- Enter: `$3` in the replace field

**How to turn 2 spaces indents in all files in VS Code to 4 spaces**

- Open file search
- Turn on Regular Expressions
- Enter: `((( {2}))(\b|(?!=[,'";\.:\\*\\\/{\}\[\]\(\)])))` in the search field
- Enter: `$3$3` in the replace field

**NOTE: You must turn on PERL Regex first. This is How:**

- Open settings and go to the JSON file
- add the following to the JSON file `"search.usePCRE2": true`

Comment: AWESOME! It worked great (running in SublimeText 3). All we had to do after was replacing all tabs with two spaces

Comment: Wow! More reasons to love coding :)

Comment: open file search ? what, where is that at ?

Comment: Excellent. Works best when you do "replace all" instead of going one-by-one.

Answer (score 9):

You probably want these in your settings:

```
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
```

Particularly the last one as it will override the prior two if set to true.

As to whether it is possible to format all files in a folder or the workspace in one go, that is not possible via built-in functionality of vscode.  However there is a new extension that looks interesting:

[format files extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jbockle.jbockle-format-files#overview) : format all files in a folder or the workspace.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for responding.  I downloaded the extension but it did not do what I originally wanted to accomplish.  BUT, that being said, its good to know that there are extensions that can be looked into in terms of making code readable at best.  Thanks.

Comment: Did the extension work across files as advertised though?  It just didn't fix your indentation issues?

Comment: So, what happens is it leaves the editor pages with red headers on lines where you have extra space or indention that you did not intend to leave behind.  For example, when you erase a code, sometimes you just erase the snippet of code but not the entire line of code.  This will create a red line across.  Which is pretty nice, so that when you copy and past a new code from another source, it does not affects the indentation.  :) . Hope that made sense.

Comment: Now `Format Files` has 84,199 install.

Comment: Is that an... extension? Link?

Comment: this really save my day

Answer (score 0):

These settings did the job for me.
You should specify not only editor but your python formatter as well.

```
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--indent-size=2"
  ]
```

Comment: This answer does not bear much relevance to projects using React. Most configuration settings here address the issue for Python, which, although may be useful, does not address the problem being asked.